# ¿Sigue funcionando este código de Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Ultimamente he estado siguiendo la serie de vídeos de Ben Eater del 6502, pero me he topado con un problema en el video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnzuMJLZRdU, en el minuto 12:00, donde las direcciones de memoria de salida son siempre iguales, y además salen muy rápido, en vez de seguir el reloj.

El código:

```
const char ADDR[] = {22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52};
#define CLOCK 2

void setup() {
  for (int n = 0; n < 16; n += 1) {
    pinMode(ADDR[n], INPUT);
  }
  pinMode(CLOCK, INPUT);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(CLOCK), onClock, RISING);
  
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void onClock() {

  for (int n = 0; n < 16; n += 1) {
    int bit = digitalRead(ADDR[n]) ? 1 : 0;
    Serial.print(bit);
  }
Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Estoy en el chat si quieres más aclaraciones

Comment: En que sala estás?

Answer (score 0):

**¿Por qué se repiten los valores?**

Porque el programa Arduino está haciendo *polling*, interrogando los pines de entrada más rápido de lo que estos cambian.

```
void loop() {
  for (int n = 0; n < 16; n += 1) {
    int bit = digitalRead(ADDR[n]) ? 1 : 0;
    Serial.print(bit);
    }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Arduino Mega opera a 16 Mhz, mientras que el 6502 de Ben usa un clock autoconstruido que debe operar a 1 Khz ...

**¿Cómo lo solucionó?**

En lugar de hacer "polling", conecto el Pin 2 (Arduino) al clock del 6502. También programó el pin 2 (Arduino) para que genere una interrupción cada vez que la señal (del clock) va de LOW (0v) a HIGH (5v).

```
pinMode(CLOCK, INPUT);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(CLOCK), onClock, RISING);
```

Ahora los valores se leen sólo cuando el clock cambia -> interrupción -> rutina de atención de interrupción, la que finalmente se encarga de leer.

```
void onClock() {

  for (int n = 0; n < 16; n += 1) {
    int bit = digitalRead(ADDR[n]) ? 1 : 0;
    Serial.print(bit);
  }
Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
   }
```

OJO: Eater está haciendo algo inapropiado dentro `onClock`, que es operar con la puerta serial. No es recomendable hacer E/S dentro de una interrupción.

Comment: Dónde esta haciendo polling el programa? Creía que funcionaba con interrupción...

Comment: @ByRussX Precisamente. La primera versión es con polling; la segunda versión es con interrupciones.